# Изучая Java задался вопросом о private class

Tags: java, классы, инкапсуляция

1. Где и как могут использоваться классы c private модификатором?
2. final class нельзя наследовать, и они используются довольно редко? (понятно что в некоторых ситуациях это может быть использовано, но не понятно в каких именно)
3. private конструкторы в обычных классах - что это и зачем? как себя ведут те же конструкторы в private class?

Comment: 1. Внутри другого класса, для отделения части внутренней логики. 2. Да, редко. Иногда надо явно запретить наследование. 3. В билдерах, например, используются. Конструкторы ничем не отличаются. |||| Лучше по одному вопрос на один вопрос задавать.

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб по второму вопросу не согласен с вами

Comment: @AzizUmarov, у нас может быть разный опыт) Я не настаиваю на том, что по статистике может оказаться, что используется это "часто".

Comment: @ЮрийСПб часто применяется в создании иммутабельных классах. Во избежании проблем с наследованием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Private часто это иннер класс и ведёт он себя как приватное поле внешнего класса.

```
    public class Pub{
       ...
       private class Priv{...}
    }
```

`Priv` доступно лишь внутри `Pub` для его личных нужд.

2. Сами объекты могут использоваться часто. Но с точки зрения эволюции final это тупиковая ветвь.

`public final class String{ }`

3. `private` конструкторы это для сокрытия создание через оператор `new`. Или по другому создание через фабричный метод.

`BigInteger big = BigInteger.valueOf(..);`